# What is the rank of $\alpha I + \beta P$ with $P^2=P$ and $\alpha,\beta>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

I have been working with projection matrices lately  and I have one additional question:

> Is it true a statement that
>   linear combination of identity matrix $I$ of rank $n$ and any projection matrix $P$ of rank less than $n$ where coefficients are **positive** i.e. matrix  $A =  {\alpha}I+{\beta}P$,    with   $  {\alpha}>0, {\beta}>0 ,$
>   has always rank $n$ ?
>
> If so how to prove it?

*If so the same is true of course for powers  $A^m$*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that $\alpha I+\beta P$ has rank $n$ is the same as saying that $P-\lambda I$ has rank $n$, where $\lambda=-\alpha/\beta$, that is, that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $P$. What are the eigenvalues of a projection matrix? Hint: $P^2=P$.

Comment: Egreg's  method is very ingenious and maybe it could be extended for more numbers of linear combinations..

Answer (score 3):

Pick a basis of the image of the projection and of its kernel. Then they combine to form a basis of the whole space and in this basis the projection is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\
&\ddots\\
&&1\\
&&&0\\
&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

so $\alpha I+\beta P$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha+\beta\\
&\ddots\\
&&\alpha+\beta\\
&&&\alpha\\
&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&\alpha
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So simple ? Hard to believe :)

Comment: But what would be in the case of two (or more) projections $A =  {\alpha}I+{\beta}P_1 + {\gamma}P_2$,    with   $  {\alpha}>0, {\beta}>0 , {\gamma }>0$, ... changing basis would not be so simple..

Comment: @Widawensen That conjecture would not be true in that form, for example $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\-2&1\end{pmatrix}$ has rank 1.

Comment: hmm,  maybe only for symmetrical projection matrices is true?

Comment: It is true in that case because it will be positive definite.

Comment: Thank You for this information. Now I know why some examples I had chosen at the first sight randomly were giving this effect.. these matrices were just symmetrical so positive definitive..

Comment: I was looking at this case more carefully lately, and .. is this matrix no strictly positive definite but positive semi-definite..?.

Comment: @Widawensen The contribution from the $\alpha I$ component is strictly positive.

Comment: Of course you're right, this component is not to be neglected. I've much learned from your answers, not only in this thread.